# Assigning part of an array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I want to fill in part of an array with the values of another array. Is there anyway I can do this without looping?

e.g.

```
int [] [] ArrayToFillIn = new int [3] [3]
int [] FillingArray = {1, 2};

for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
{
    ArrayToFillIn [i-1] [2] = FillingArray [i - 1];
}
```

in R it would be like:

```
ArrayToFillIn [c(1:2),3] = FillingArray []
```

(considering that R does not start from 0)

Thanks!

Comment: Why wouldnt you loop?

Comment: Normally you would use `Arrays.copyOfRange`, but because you're inserting across a 2D array you may not be able to leverage that without loops anyway.

Comment: Java doesn't have that sort of array splicing functionality.

Comment: Could you provide an example of the output you want to produce with your example input data?

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Without a loop it would be

```
ArrayToFillIn [0] [2] = FillingArray [0];
ArrayToFillIn [1] [2] = FillingArray [1];
```

Comment: I think The OP is talking about the general case :3

Answer (score 0):

What with this initialization:

```
int [] FillingArray = {1, 2};
int [][] ArrayToFillIn = new int[][]{{0, 0, FillingArray[0]}, {0, 0, FillingArray[1]}, {}};
//---------------------------------------------^-----------------------^----------------^
```